# Two way binding in jsp

Tags: angular, spring-mvc, jsp, web, jsp-tags

I have written a web application using spring mvc and angular.Now I want to convert the angular code to jsp.So,  I want to simulate ng-model in angular to jsp.Is it possible to replace ng-model with some jsp equivalent?I want two way binding.If possible please Illustrate.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="modal-body-right-content-2" ng-model="${p[0].age}" id="modal_input_box_name"/>
```

Here  class "modal-body-right-content-2" is used for styling using css,
p is an array of objects with attributes age,name,gender.
p is returned by spring mvc controller

Spring MVC controller

```
package com.jeswin.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import data.Person;

import javax.print.DocFlavor.STRING;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject; 


@Controller
public class CrunchifyHelloWorld 
{

    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {


        Person p[]=new Person[5];
        p[0]=new Person(22,"Rahem","Male");
        p[1]=new Person(23,"Shobha","Female");
        p[2]=new Person(22,"Rahem","Male");
        p[3]=new Person(42,"Rahema","Female");
        p[4]=new Person(22,"Rahem","Male");


        return new ModelAndView("welcome", "p", p);
    }
},
```

Comment: It will be much helpful if you share some code snippets.Thanks

Comment: Thanks bro.edited

Answer (score 0):

You can use jstl tag to display your values,but there is no concept of two way binding in jsp.

```
 <c:forEach items="${p}" var="values">
       ${values}
</c:forEach>
```

And do add jstl dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>jstl</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Also you can use spel (Spring expression language to display data)